# Is this dialog an android Notification?

Tags: android, notifications, alarm, standby

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO1aq.jpg)

System:Android 10.0 (Huawei EMUI 10.0)

Is the window(or dialog) shown at the bottom of the screen an android Notification?

It's a clock remind window from a clock app. As you can see in the image, the app's main window does not show. Only the dialog can pop up when the phone is in standby. I want to realize the same clock window function.

It seems like a notification because if I turn off the permission of the app's notification, it can not show.

But I don't know how to show a notification at the bottom of screen while not at the notification bar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No window is showing

Comment: It's bottomsheet

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin  Thanks for reply. The app's main window does not show, only this dialog pops up from the phone's home page. So I think it can't be a bottomsheet. Is it possible a  local notification?

Comment: Have you changed your picture? I don't see anything at the bottom of screen.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Maybe last picture is not so clear for the question. I have just changed a new picture. Please review it. Thanks.

Comment: It's new feature in Android 10, see here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.techrepublic.com/google-amp/article/how-to-manage-notifications-in-android-10/

Comment: Do you get your answer?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Thanks a lot for your reply. But I can't find the answer from that article. There is no notification example shown at the bottom of phone screen in that article. The keypoint of my question is how to show my notification on the "bottom" of the screen  like the way of that app realize as the picture I post.

Comment: As you asked "is-this-dialog-an-android-notification" and the answer according to site I linked is yes I think, in Andrlod 10 user can change notification style. Now how to implement it is another question. So I think it's better to ask another question.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Sorry, I failed to make my question clear. I just want to know what technique is that dialog in the picture and how to implement the same function. I have changed my question... And from the site you linked, it seems that it tells a phone user how to manage the notification，while not list all the notifaction style for developer,  and I can't find a notification style in the artcle shown "on the bottom" of the screen.  So I still wonder if there is way to set a notification to be shown on the bottom. If you know that, could you please give some instruction? Thank you.

Comment: It's better to ask another question. You have edited your question and answer will be changed. It needs code to answer this new question.

Comment: ok, I'll start a new question : )

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I have asked another question, could you please answer on that question? Thank you so much.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040568/how-to-implement-a-notificaiton-dialog-in-android-10-as-in-this-picture

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Can you reply that question? There isn't a reply until now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's new feature in Android 10 that you can change notification style. See here for more details:
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-manage-notifications-in-android-10/